# Cosa significa “da urlo”?

Tags: idioms, vocabulary

Ho un dubbio. Ho visto l'espressione in un articolo e non so cosa vuol dire. Che cosa significa “da urlo”? Nell'articolo appare l'espressione “capelli da urlo”.

Cosa significa “da urlo”?

Comment: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/urlo/

Comment: Benvenuta/o su Italian.SE, @FlordeSião!

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer to your question, please consider the option to "accept" it by clicking a checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

L'espressione "da urlo" viene utilizzata (nel linguaggio parlato e direi piuttosto giovanile) per indicare qualcosa di talmente bello, straordinario, ... da meritare un "urlo" di meraviglia.

Quindi, "capelli da urlo" sono capelli che si notano molto, pettinati in modo molto bello o comunque che non passano inosservati.

Answer (score 0):

**[Da urlo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/urlo/)**:

> con altro uso figurativo, nell'espressione del gergo giovanile *"da urlo"*, di cosa o persona che colpisce vivamente per alcune sue doti o qualità (con significato simile a *forza*, *schianto*).

Esempio di uso:

> "La mia ragazza indossava un abito **da urlo**."

Comment: Per favore, @ilMagnifico, usa il formato "quote" per le citazioni, come ho fatto in questo tuo post.